# ProcessBuilder unable to call python scripts in the resource folder

Tags: java, python-3.x

I have an executable jar which has python scripts(under resources) getting called from a java class using processbuilder

```
String processBuilderPath = new String(workingDirectory + "\\pythonScripts\\rcExceptionProcessor.py");
ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder("python",processBuilderPath,rcExcpField.getText(),outputField.getText());
```

**In the IDE it is working fine** since it is taking the target folder path to get the .py file I am looking for. But once I make the executable jar from the project, the **jar is unable to locate the python scripts inside it**. The work around is to keep the pythonScript folder with the executable jar outside from wherever I am running it. But I cannot give this work around to the client.
What would be the best solution for this problem ?

Comment: You can't execute scripts from within a JAR/ZIP file. Extract the script to a temporary file and execute it from there.

Comment: Thanks for the response Robert. This jar needs to be delivered to the customer we cannot give the script files separately with the jar file. What is the work around ?

Comment: Read the second sentence of my comment. Do this by Java code at runtime of your program.